# Como redirecionar uma URL sempre com barra (/) no final?

Tags: apache, redirecionamento-de-url, mod-rewrite

Tenho esse código:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Quando digito `http://localhost/path` eu gostaria que ele redirecionasse para: `http://localhost/path/`

**Gostaria de fazer isso sem mudar meu código base:**
No código acima quando você coloca `http://localhost/path` ele redireciona para o index.php (quero manter isso).
Quero que o meu código fique flexível para aceitar qualquer mudança de URL e para aceitar tanto http quanto https.
Também quero que ele detecte a pasta que o meu site tá caso mude de pasta. Exemplo:
 De `localhost/` para `localhost/www/site`
E não quero que ele ignore caminho de arquivos e diretórios existentes.

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

As linhas com `!-f` e `!-d` fazem com que a regra não funcione se for um caminho de arquivo ou diretório existetes.

Você precisa ver no seu caso prático se é isto mesmo que quer quando for lidar com imagens e arquivos estáticos. Podem ser necessárias regras extras, dependendo do resultado desejado.

Comment: Não teria como ficar mais compatível? E se eu quiser colocar o https no meu site? E se o domínio do meu site mudar?

Comment: o `RewriteRule` vc pode mudar como quiser, e deixar sem o protocolo e o domínio. o importante é o `$1/`.

Comment: Então pode ficar assim: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L, R=301]`?

Comment: Bacco você poderia melhorar o código para ele ficar mais flexivel?

Comment: @RowAraujo seria legal você editar a pergunta e acrescentar os detalhes que precisa (só procure não alterar o sentido original dela, mas acrescente exemplos de URLs entradas e as respectivas conversões desejadas)

Comment: Pronto Bacco!!!

Comment: @RowAraujo atualizei. Na verdade só removi o protocolo e o URL, e comecei da / .

Comment: Só mais uma coisinha: Meu site está em localhost, mas está em `localhost/www/site` e quando eu coloco algum path ele redireciona para `localhost/path`

Comment: @RowAraujo se vc acessar por http://127.0.0.1/path ele faz o que?

Comment: Ele acessa outra pasta, e meu site está em `localhost/www/site/`

Comment: E eu quero que para todo `path` ele redirecione para o arquivo `index.php` que ta na pasta raiz. Como faz meu código lá em cima na pergunta.